# Highcharts xAxis Categories not Dsiplaying Properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got 7 "Areas" in my data that I am trying to make a Highcharts stacked bar chart for. My Categories are not showing up correctly only the first one in the middle of the axis. Any idea why? Desired results would be the 7 Areas running down the left side and each of their two sets of data stacked next to each other Green first then Red.

Fiddle Here [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rplace13/7sorc0ju/10/)

```
Highcharts.chart('graphContainer', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Area Dashboard'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    uniqueNames: true,
    categories: ["Capital Metro (K)", "Eastern (C)", "Great Lakes (J)", "Northeast (B)", "Pacific (F)", "Southern (S)", "Western (E)"],
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    "name": "Capital Metro (K)",
    "data": [11],
    "stack": "Capital Metro (K)",
    "color": "Red"
  }, {
    "name": "Capital Metro (K)",
    "data": [4],
    "stack": "Capital Metro (K)",
    "color": "Green"
  }, {
    "name": "Eastern (C)",
    "data": [1],
    "stack": "Eastern (C)",
    "color": "Red"
  }, {
    "name": "Eastern (C)",
    "data": [0],
    "stack": "Eastern (C)",
    "color": "Green"
  }, {
    "name": "Great Lakes (J)",
    "data": [0],
    "stack": "Great Lakes (J)",
    "color": "Red"
  }, {
    "name": "Great Lakes (J)",
    "data": [1],
    "stack": "Great Lakes (J)",
    "color": "Green"
  }, {
    "name": "Northeast (B)",
    "data": [1],
    "stack": "Northeast (B)",
    "color": "Red"
  }, {
    "name": "Northeast (B)",
    "data": [0],
    "stack": "Northeast (B)",
    "color": "Green"
  }, {
    "name": "Pacific (F)",
    "data": [13],
    "stack": "Pacific (F)",
    "color": "Red"
  }, {
    "name": "Pacific (F)",
    "data": [6],
    "stack": "Pacific (F)",
    "color": "Green"
  }, {
    "name": "Southern (S)",
    "data": [1],
    "stack": "Southern (S)",
    "color": "Red"
  }, {
    "name": "Southern (S)",
    "data": [0],
    "stack": "Southern (S)",
    "color": "Green"
  }, {
    "name": "Western (E)",
    "data": [1],
    "stack": "Western (E)",
    "color": "Red"
  }, {
    "name": "Western (E)",
    "data": [0],
    "stack": "Western (E)",
    "color": "Green"
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current options, each series has only one point, connected to the first category.

Instead, create two series (one green, one red) with all points in data: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7sorc0ju/11/

Snippet:

```
series: [{
  "name": "Capital Metro (K)",
  "data": [11, 1, 0, 1, 13, 1, 1],
  "stack": "Capital Metro (K)",
  "color": "Red"
}, {
  "name": "Capital Metro (K)",
  "data": [4, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0],
  "stack": "Capital Metro (K)",
  "color": "Green"
}]
```